# The argument type 'BorderRadius?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BorderRadiusGeometry' because 'BorderRadius?' is nullable

Tags: flutter

I am getting the below error it looks like flutter_advanced_networkimage_2-2.0.1 is not null safety compatible. We experience this with flutter 3.13 but when downgrading to flutter 3.10 we don't get this error.

Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 arm64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_advanced_networkimage_2-2.0.1/lib/src/transition/transition_to_image.dart:415:50: Error: The argument type 'BorderRadius?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BorderRadiusGeometry' because 'BorderRadius?' is nullable and 'BorderRadiusGeometry' isn't.

- 'BorderRadius' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/border_radius.dart' ('../../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/border_radius.dart').
- 'BorderRadiusGeometry' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/border_radius.dart' ('../../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/border_radius.dart').
  borderRadius: widget.borderRadius,

dennisvanmaren@Denniss-MacBook-Pro scholiertje % flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.7, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-NL)
• Flutter version 3.13.7 on channel stable at /Users/dennisvanmaren/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 2f708eb839 (4 days ago), 2023-10-09 09:58:08 -0500
• Engine revision a794cf2681
• Dart version 3.1.3
• DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/dennisvanmaren/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 15A240d
• CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
• macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 118.0.5993.70

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

Downgrading to flutter 3.10.0 resolved the issue